# Error: Can't resolve 'fs' and Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '.\node_modules\bindings' after libxmljs is added in angular 13 project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

My angular project has started giving error during build post addition of **libxmljs** package. But strange thing is error is pointing to folder - **\node_modules\bindings** instead of \node_modules\libxmljs.

Only code change -

`"libxmljs": "^0.19.7"` in `package.json`

and

`let xsdDoc = libxmljs.parseXml(xsdFile);` in `myproject.component.ts`

My environment -

```
Node v18.0.0
NPM 8.6.0
No angular CLI. Its maven project.
```

Error log -

```
...
[INFO] ./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:4:9-22 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\my-frontend\node_modules\bindings'
[INFO]
[INFO] ./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:5:11-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\my-frontend\node_modules\bindings'
[INFO]
[INFO] BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
[INFO] This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
[INFO]
[INFO] If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
[INFO]  - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
[INFO]  - install 'path-browserify'
[INFO] If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
[INFO]  resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  07:51 min
...
```

Troubleshoot -

1. Tried `"browser": { "fs": false, "path":false }` with no luck.
2. Tried webpack.config.js but same issue.

Is this a bug in libxmljs and should I find other way to validate xmls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `node_modules/bindings` specific bug.
I resolved issue by switching to java using `javax.xml`.
Sample code for war based app -

```
@PostMapping("/xml/validate")
    public ResourceEntity<Boolean> validateXmlWithXSD(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required = true) String token, int xsdVersion, @RequestBody ProjectXml processIn) {
        //step- initializations
        ...
        try {
            //step- session validation
            ...

            //step- xsd access from webapp
            String xsdPath = "/assets/xsds/ProjectXsd." + xsdVersion + ".xsd";
            InputStream xsdStream = request.getSession().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(xsdPath);
            if(xsdStream==null)
                throw new NullPointerException("Null xsd stream.");

            //step- xml validation against xsd
            Source source = new StreamSource(xsdStream);
            Schema schema = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(source);
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(processIn.getProcessXML())));
            isValidated = true;
        } catch (SAXException | IOException | NullPointerException e) {
            ...
        }
        //step- return result
    }
```

In case of spring-boot jar app,

```
                //step- xsd access from target/classes
                String xsdPath = "/assets/xsds/ProjectXsd." + xsdVersion + ".xsd";
                InputStream xsdStream = new ClassPathResource(xsdPath).getInputStream();
```

and in maven I configured

```
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/assets/runtimeXsds</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
```